# What could measuring the N400 response to stimuli of inconsistent stereotypes tell us?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, eeg

I'm working on a project proposal for a class on intergroup relations and thought this might be interesting to observe. Participants would be shown consistent stereotypical video clips (e.g. Asian's doing rubics cubes, white girl ordering a psl, etc.), neutral video clips (kid going to school????) and inconsistent (female car mechanic, male nurse). We would then observe the N400 component and recall accuracy after maybe a 48 hour time period.

I am hoping this would give more insight into how well people can retain inconsistent schemas, what the cognitive load of making sense of inconsistent schemas are in relation to other variable types of N400 stimulation (such as language), and how this impacts memory.

I would really appreciate feedback on the design. I honestly really like the idea and I haven't seen anything like it. If you have seen a similar study, or want to point out errors in the experimental design that would be great! Also, comment on study implications you can think of.

If you think it's just altogether a terrible idea, I will not be offended either! That is what scientific communities are for after all.